# Google App engine user authentication (python 3.7)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I am looking for a **simple** method to authenticate (using Goggle account) users into an python 3.7 app running on GAE.
In the past (using python 2.7) I have used 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/loginurls
and the logic was something like:

```
def my_end_point():
   if user is not authenticated:
       redirect_to_google_login()
   else:
      user_email = get_user_email_from_auth_service()
      do_the_endpoint_logic(user_email)
```

I would like to keep this simple logic under GAE python 3.7

I have found [this](https://github.com/realpython/materials/blob/master/flask-google-login/app.py) and I was wondering if someone wrapped this logic with decorator..

any directions?

Answer (score 0):

The the App Engine standard environment Python 3.7 runtime does not support the Users API service. Your options are:

- [Firebase Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/authenticating-users#firebase_authentication)
- [Google Sign-In](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/authenticating-users#google_sign-in)
- [OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/authenticating-users#oauth_20_and_openid_connect)

  - via https://pypi.org/project/Flask-OAuthlib
  - via https://authlib.org

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of those 3 options. I was looking for a lib that wraps OAuth and integrates well with Flask.

Comment: Thanks. As of today [August-2019] it looks like https://authlib.org/ is the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (Januari 2022), the Python 3.x runtime does support the `Users API` by means of the App Engine bundled services. There is a very detailed and straightforward [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access) page on how to enable this in App Engine.

Several other options for user authentication are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/authenticating-users).